# How to remove directive before it gets processed by angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that encapsulates a label and an input field:

```
<form-field label="Name" ng-model="person.name"></form-field>
```

Directive definition:

```
app.directive("formField", function(){
    var ignoreAttrs = ["label"];
    return {
      priority: 3, //so it executes before ngModel.
      template: "<div>" +
                     "<label>{{label}}</label>" +
                     "<input type='text' />" +
                    "</div>",
      scope: true,
      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
        var $input = tElement.find("input");

        //copy attributes from directive element to inner input field
        var attrs = [];
        $.each(tElement[0].attributes, function(index, attr){
          if(ignoreAttrs.indexOf(attr.label) < 0){
            attrs.push(attr.name);
            $input.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
          }
        });

        //remove the attributes from the directive element
        $.each(attrs, function(index, attr){
          tElement.removeAttr(attr);
        });

        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs){
          scope.label = attrs.label;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

The problem I'm running into is that when angular traverses the DOM it finds two directives: form-field and ng-model. This causes the ng-model to get set up in the **form-field** element and then in the **input**, when my intent is to only have ng-model in the **input**.

Is there a way to tell angular to ignore a directive or is there an earlier moment in the lifecycle when I can run the logic that copies and removes the attributes so angular does not find the ng-model directive in the form-field?

A possible solution could be to have all other directives have a prefix so angular does not recognize them, then in compile function of the **form-field** I could remove the prefix before copying to the **input** but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: try during compile phase.. remove the attribute.. store it, and then during post-link add it back

Comment: The basic idea, moving ng-model around, is wrong. Require ng-model in directive, and then use the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) methods to get ($render), and set ($setViewValue) the model value. Look at the example at the of the ngModelController doc page.

Comment: templateUrl: "<div>..."? You need to use template: "<...>..." or templateUrl and to put the html on a external file

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo that was a copy/paste error. Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign directive attributes to an element in template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657670/assign-directive-attributes-to-an-element-in-template)

Comment: @estus thanks for the reference however the accepted answer uses the prefix solution that I talked about above. I would like to see if there is a different solution.

Comment: I think that prefixes are clean enough, this way you explicitly specify which attributes have to be translated to nested element and which ones are meant for the directive itself.

Answer (score 1):

Since `terminate` may cause undesirable side-effects, the most simple and trouble-free solution is to decorate the directives to keep them from compiling:

```
app.config(function($provide){
  var blacklistedDirectives = ['ngModel'];

  angular.forEach(blacklistedDirectives, function (directive) {
    $provide.decorator(directive + 'Directive', function ($delegate) {
      angular.forEach($delegate, function (ddo) {
        var compile_ = ddo.compile || function () {};

        ddo.compile = function (element) {
          if (element.attr('form-field') !== undefined || element.prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'form-field')
            return;

          return compile_.apply(this, arguments) || ddo.link;
        };
      });

      return $delegate;
    });
  });
});
```