# Angular - Cannot get custom directive to cooperate with ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change

I have a very simple directive (named `cooperate-with-ng-change`) which requires `ng-model` and I'd like it to cooperate with `ng-change`.

Restated, I'd like to be able to do `<cooperate-with-ng-change ng-model="model" ng-change="changeHandler()"></cooperate-with-ng-change>`

However I'm noticing when `changeHandler()` is fired, `model` is the old value and not the new one.

Here's the directive definition object:

```
return {
    restrict: "E",
    require: ["ngModel"],
    scope: {
      "value": "=ngModel"
    },
    template: "<label>Cooperate with NgChange: <input type='text' ng-model='value' ng-model-options='{debounce: 500}' /></label>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
      var inputNgModelCtrl = element.find("input").controller("ngModel");
      var parentNgModelCtrl = ctrls[0];


      Array.prototype.push.apply(inputNgModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners, parentNgModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners)

      //if I wrap all the parentNgModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners in a timeout and digest in changeHandler
      //then message matches afterDebounce
      /*Array.prototype.push.apply(inputNgModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners,
        parentNgModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.map(
          function(listener) {
            return function() {
              setTimeout(listener, 1)
            }
          }))
      */
    }
  }
```

[Here's a plunker link if you want to play with it](http://plnkr.co/edit/GUBgNJxV4pilJpMxloXh)

My guess is `$viewChangeListeners` gets called before the model value is set, however I can't find what might correspond for after the model value is set.

Comment: what problem is this trying to solve? Can't understand why you need to use `ng-change` on directive element and don't just pass the change handler into directive scope through another attribute name

Comment: So you're suggesting that I use a different name for what should be the same functionality.  Okay. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign directive attributes to an element in template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657670/assign-directive-attributes-to-an-element-in-template)

Comment: Yes,  `ng-change` is an event handling directive for form controls so to me it makes no sense using it on your directive to pass an object inside. It is not the same functionality!

Comment: I don't think you understand what's going on here.  Consider this scenario `<custom-directive ng-model='someResource' ng-change='someResource.$save()' ng-model-options='{debounce: 500}'></custom-directive>`.  `custom-directive` can encapsulate those form components.  How is this any different than `<input type='text' ng-model='someResource.someProperty' ng-change='someResource.$save()' />`?  In any case, I got my use case to work properly so don't spend more time here than you want to. :)

Comment: Can you post your solution? I've also been struggling with this.